# Minecraft Server keeps crashing out of memory, but stil empty swap left

Tags: server, java, minecraft

I am trying to run a spigot server on my ubuntu vps (openVZ). The problem is that I receive "Killed" messages that shuts the server down. After a bit research i found out that there is not enough memory, but i have the min and the max memory (java) set to 512M (before i had 1G but there were even more crashes). I understand why processses are killed because of too much ram usage, but I dont understand why these processes are not using the swap (2gb).

Thanks for your allways fast answers.

---

PS: back in the dasy, i had the same server running without any problems. I dont know what I am doing wrong right now

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate manually how much RAM java can use for minecraft. From [Minecraft Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server)

> Using the Xms and Xmx parameters, the initial and maximum memory size
>   for Java can be specified. By default, your server runs with about 100
>   MB of RAM, which is very little. Most people will change their server
>   to run with more, for example:
>
> ```
> java -Xms512M -Xmx1G ...
> java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M ...
> java -Xms1G -Xmx2G ...
> ```

Comment: That's not what I want. I said I played with the xms and xmx values a bit but that doesn't change anything. The system (!) is killing the server I think

Answer (score 0):

Java memory handling is a bit special.

I don't know it much in details, but you should perhaps rise XMX and XMS settings.

Minecraft won't use your swap : it's a dedicated space managed by linux kernel : if your system runs out of memory, the kernel will decide to swap informations, but JAVA will first limit Minecraft server to the memory size you allowed it via command line.

Your server did run well last days, because MineCraft do expand his "map storage file" as the map is visited/crafted.

So, first days, your map was small enough to fit in allocated memory, and then I suppose it did growed as players crawled around...

Comment: first: thanks for the fast reply and wecome to askubuntu (me too :P)

To make this clear: back then, the map wasnt smaller, the server was just not running for a few month. But now, i try 3G (cause with 2G it happenes to crash too). But wouldnt a too small XMX throw an exception instead of letting the SYSTEM "kill" the process?

Comment: Tested it with 3G but I think it's still not working

Comment: As I said, I'm not a Java expert, but I think that memory shortage would throw an "OutOfMemoryErrorException", also known as "Java Heap Space". I don't think the system decides by itself to kill the server, that's not a decision Linux would take by its own ! Can you run the server in a terminal (example, in gnome-terminal), and then see what output it gives when being "killed" ?

Comment: If you can't let the window open, you can search at "screen" which is a software which allow to "detach" a terminal in background and then re-open it later !

Comment: Thanks, I know how to run these. If I set the memory limit to 128M, this causes the server to throw an OutOfMemoryException and die. But that's not the case, in this case I get the usual systems message "Killed" which appears if the system decided to kill it. Btw the line before varies everything, is no exception just the last status line

Comment: That's really weird ! I don't see any reason for the server being killed !

Comment: Me too, but I think this has gone the same way it appeared. I don't know what was happening but now my ssh login (and the "login" command or su) freezes for 20 seconds before initiating bash. But that's another story

Answer (score 0):

You could go to the software center and search for mc-server and this application will pop up a mc server installer install the application agree to the eula then if you want change the server.properties. In the snap menu with the mc server installer you get to choose how much ram you want like 4G 2G and up to 12G